# Fast/Easy apporach to CUDA convolution of 2D image?

Tags: cuda

Do you have patience to answer an novice?

(I am rephrasing the question based on replies.)

I need to convolve a kernel (16x16 float ) over many 2K x 2K images (float). Is there something already in the cuBLAS or cuFFT (for cuFFT I assume I would have to convert the image and the kernel to Fourier space first) for doing this? (Let's assume I can't use openCV or NPP unless it is to copy the source).

Which option would you take:

1. Use CuFFT and convert the image and the kernel to Fourier space, filter, then inverse FFT?
2. Roll my own along the lines the NVIDA SDK and of: https://www.evl.uic.edu/sjames/cs525/final.html
3. Look at doing a box filter, and use a integral (summed image).

Comment: As pointed out in your link, the nvidia separable convolution sample code is pretty fast, and [includes a whitepaper](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-separable-convolution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement the algorithm, using the UIUC student's paper and the white paper from Nvidia. Thanks Robert.